# TS error when descturturing Block scoped variable cannot be used before its declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Hi guys I have the following code written in typescript

```
  const {
      data: { pageCollection }
    } = await apolloClient.query<PageSlugsQuery>({ query: GET_PAGE_SLUGS })


    ( [...(pageCollection?.items ?? [])].forEach((page) => {
      console.log('PAGEEE', page)
    }))
```

Whe I use the second line I'm getting the error `Block scoped variable pageCollection can not be used before its declaration`

And when I remove brackets in the second line

```
  [...(pageCollection?.items ?? [])].forEach((page) => {
      console.log('PAGEEE', page)
    })
```

then I get the following error  `Cannot find name 'forEach'.`

Does anyone know what could be a potential problem?

Comment: FWIW, I suggest using a code formatter that formats on save, like Prettier (though I recommend changing its `tabWidth` to `4` -- `2` is just too hard to read for lots of people with slightly impacted vision). If you had been using one, it would have reformatted the code moving the second statement up and joining it with the first, hopefully making the problem apparent. (It can also insert semicolons for you when formatting, so the JavaScript parser doesn't have to do its error correction stuff when you're running the code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a missing `;` that isn't optional. You need it at the end of the first statement because otherwise JavaScript (and TypeScript) think the second statement is part of it:

```
const {
    data: { pageCollection },
} = await apolloClient.query<PageSlugsQuery>({ query: GET_PAGE_SLUGS }); // <===
[...(pageCollection?.items ?? [])].forEach((page) => {
    console.log("PAGEEE", page);
});
```

If you're going to code relying on automatic semicolon insertion, it's important to be sure you know the rules for where you **need** an explicit semicolon. In general, if a line starts with a `(` or `[`, you need the `;` at the end of the previous line (technically it varies depending on what the previous line is, but it's safer just to always do it).

---

Side note: There's no need for the spread where you're calling `forEach`, just:

```
(pageCollection?.items ?? []).forEach((page) => {
    console.log("PAGEEE", page);
});
```

And I'd use `for-of` instead, but it's a matter of style:

```
for (const page of pageCollection?.items ?? []) {
    console.log("PAGEEE", page);
}
```

Comment: yes thank you I solved it it meantime, but thank you that was the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const {
      data
    } = await apolloClient.query<PageSlugsQuery>({ query: GET_PAGE_SLUGS })


const items = data?.pageCollection?.items ?? []

items.forEach((page) => {
      console.log('PAGEEE', page)
})
```

Make the code like this. This might work

Comment: What did you change? Why did you change it? What was the problem? Code dumps aren't generally useful answers. It's important to say *what* you did, and *why*.